# Micro-controller Recommendation

Tags: microcontroller

I am going to build an IoT water flow meter. And I am using below meter:

Which generated a pulse every time its meter completes a rotation. My objective is to read that pulse and send that reading data to the cloud using the GSM module. But when there is no Internet connection(GPRS) the controller should store the values of the counter to its EEPROM(Flash Memory) and when device comes online it should send it to the cloud. The device will send data every 2-5 min. I will make multiple these types of devices and from which one(Alpha) will be collecting and sending data to the cloud using the GSM module and others will send data to this(Alpha) module via RS485 or other.

The problem is I am not able to choose which microcontroller would be best for this purpose and unable to find MCU which has storage size between 50kb-1MB so that it can store large amounts of data. I don't want to add external EEPROM to it. And also selected MCU should be programmable using Arduino IDE.

I have thought of using the ESP32 GSM Module Board to do this. But it's EEPROM memory is low. And I don't have any IDEA how much storage is good for this purpose.

The budget with this water flow meter is low. So suggest me an MCU which will work for me or whose storage will be enough.

[image]

Comment: I assume that meter goes up to 99999 before it overflows to 00000, so a single 32-bit unsigned int would be more than enough to store the count while the device is offline... what do you need 50 KB for?

Comment: @Romen Yeah you are right. I was just thinking of a worst-case scenario but leave it. Just out of curiosity will the ATMEGA328P will be sufficient?

And can you suggest some micro-controller with 32bit unsigned int that can be programmed with Arduino IDE?

Comment: What are your power constraints? Will your reader be powered from AC or a battery? Hint: battery-powered GPRS is hard due to current peaks.

Comment: @Lucifer, The ATMEGA329P has 1KB of integrated EEPROM, and if a CPU doesn't natively support 32-bit arithmetic it can still be implemented with multiple smaller integers. That is something the programming language & compiler that comes with the Arduino IDE will handle automatically for various Arduino-compatible devices.

Comment: @Romen thank you. I will be searching for more. What do you think about this: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms470r1b1m.pdf. Also, can I program this with Arduino IDE?

Comment: @JanDorniak it will be powered from a battery. But I am thinking of using ESP 32 GSM module.

Comment: @Romen As you said 32-bit unsigned int Microcontroller would be enough. I was reading this post: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=562057.0/. I got to know that for two-digit int you need 4-byte storage in EEPROM so for 99999 I will need 10 bytes of storage.  Sorry If I am not understanding correctly. 
As per my application the counter will be storing it in EEPROM like 100 then 101 then 102. It will update it continuously till the network isn't online.

Comment: Will 1kb be enough and can handle this thing.

Comment: @Lucifer, 4 bytes is 32 bits. An unsigned int means those bytes only stores positive integers. With 32-bits you can store `2^32` different numbers, so a maximum of `2,147,483,647`. Pretty much *any* microcontroller with EEPROM will be capable of counting with a 32-bit number, you should be more concerned with power consumption as Jan Dorniak pointed out.

Comment: @Lucifer, I'm also not sure where you found that "for two-digit int you need 4-byte storage". That isn't correct: 1 byte can store `0 to 255` or `-128 to 127`. Any 2 digit integer, positive or negative, could be stored in just 1 byte. With 2 bytes you can store a range of `65536` different numbers, which is still a bit short for storing `99999`. That means the next integer size at 4-bytes is the smallest size of integer you can use to store `99999`. 4 bytes is tiny compared to 1KB (1000 bytes). 1KB is more than enough.

Comment: @Romen Thanks you. Now I understand it. This bytes thing was from the Arduino forum which I read. I have mentioned in the above comments. There was also something about I can only write in EEPROM about 100k times, I don't know whether it is for the overall life of EEPROM or any. Because I am going to use this project for a very long time. As Jan Dorniak said, I am also working on the power supply.

Comment: @Romen I think EEPROM will be a problem as my project will be used continuously for a long time. Due its limit of 100k erase/write. I have also read that I can read up to 4 digits of data from the analog(pulse read) pin. I don't know how much of this is correct. Also, what do you guys recommend as backup storage in case of GPRS failure EEPROM, SD Card or any other?

Comment: @Lucifer, A microcontroller *also* has RAM to store that counter, so the counter doesn't have to "live" in the EEPROM by writing to it excessively. It's up to you to determine how often the device actually *backs up* the counter to EEPROM to balance the accuracy of your count over power failures vs EEPROM wearing out. If the meter outputs an absolute value (via analog pulses) then you might not even need to back up the counter value at all!

Comment: @Romen The meter just sents the pulse it doesn't give the absolute values. That's a bummer. I also thought of storing the values in a variable in case of GPRS failure but if by any chance device resets the values will be lost. I think if I neglect the time and date stamp (Because when sent to the cloud it will store there with timestamp) then just have to store values.

Comment: I am gonna try by creating a dummy counter in the Arduino and print those values every 2 min to the console and when I hit a button or write stop on the console the counter data starts to store on the EEPROM. I will then again write Start to start printing on the console.